# Toggle width and height using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an icon on my website which displays a drop-down menu if clicked. I want to add another property to this icon to toggle it's width and height. I have tried the following code, but unfortunately it does not work.

```
    $ (".menu_icon").click(function() {

    var iconWidth;
    var iconHeight;

    $ ("#dropDownMenu").toggle(600);

    if ($(".menu_icon").width() == "30px") {
      iconWidth = "15px";
      iconHeight = "15px";
    } 
    else {
      iconWidth = "30px";
      iconHeight = "30px";
    }
    $(".menu_icon").animate({ width: iconWidth });
    $(".menu_icon").animate({ height: iconHeight });

  });
```

CSS Properties for .menu_icon:

```
 .menu_icon  {
    float: left;  
    margin-top: 7px;  
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(..url to icon image);
    padding: 10px;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;    
}
```

When the icon is clicked, it toggles its width and height to 30px; however, it will keep this size even if it is clicked the second time.
Many thanks

Comment: Try `$("#menu_icon").width() == 30`

Comment: Does not work either

Comment: are you sure your menu icon both has class `.menu_icon` and **id** `#menu_icon`?

Comment: yes sir, the menu_icon size changes to 30px when clicked.. but it will not toggle back to 15 when clicked the second time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width() returns a numeric value so the problem seems on the 8th line of your JS code. Here is modified version of your code (a little bit optimized). Hope it helps.

```
$(".menu_icon").click(function() {
    var iconProps = { width: "30px", height: "30px" };
    $ ("#dropDownMenu").toggle(600);

    if ($("#menu_icon").width() >= 30) {
        iconProps.width = '15px';
        iconProps.height = '15px';
    }

    $(".menu_icon").animate(iconProps);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width) returns an numerical value, not a string value so

> The difference between .css(width) and .width() is that the latter
>   returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former
>   returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The .width()
>   method is recommended when an element's width needs to be used in a
>   mathematical calculation.

```
if ($(".menu_icon").width() == 30) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are specifying  ID in your $("#menu_icon") , try to use $(".menu_icon") in your if condition or use $(this) instead. Try to use ON event of jquery.

```
    $ (".menu_icon").on('click',function() {

      var iconWidth;
      var iconHeight;

     $ ("#dropDownMenu").toggle(600);

     if ($(this).width() == 30) {
       iconWidth = "15px";
       iconHeight = "15px";
     } else {
      iconWidth = "30px";
      iconHeight = "30px";
     }
     $(this).animate({ width: iconWidth });
     $(this).animate({ height: iconWidth });

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

try without using pixels: i.e. `if ($("#menu_icon").width() == 30)`

If you wont require animate then just try toggle class i.e.

```
//.css file
.fullWidth
{
height:30px;
width:30px;
}

//.jsfile
//no need of if ($("#menu_icon").width() == 30 just use toggle class
$ (".menu_icon").click(function() {

    $ ("#dropDownMenu").toggle(600);

    $(".menu_icon").toggleClass('fullWidth');

  });
```